# Formula is to big to execute...What else can I use to write a formula for a field

Tags: formula, formula-field, error, force

Hi I am just wondering if I wanted to write a formula that computes a number for specific field, how else can I go about doing this? I am currently using the advanced formula section for the field and it gives me this error:

```
Error: Compiled formula is too big to execute (9,087 characters). Maximum size is 5,000 characters
```

When I literally wrote this 1 line of code:

```
IF(Commission_Adjustable__c >=0,(Commission_Percentage__c  * Subtotal__c) + Commission_Adjustable__c, (Commission_Percentage__c  * Subtotal__c) - Commission_Adjustable__c)
```

Please can someone help me, how else can I write this code.

Comment: Are the fields is the above formal also formula fields? The compile size is not the numbers of characters. It also is a combination of ALL formulas in the formula. If you cannot get it to work using a formula you may have to goto a trigger. Salesforce has a whole document around this: http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/202/9/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_formula_size_tipsheet.pdf

Comment: Yes,  only two of the three fields listed above are formula's. The Subtotal and Commission Percentage are formula's, but the Commission Adjustable is just a number field. Also If I made a trigger to calculate this formula...would I still need this field???

Answer (score 0):

You could revert to workflows or triggers to (part of) the calculation but we would also aim at reducing the size of this formula and/or the formula fields being referenced. This is far less complex so should be your first option.

E.g. referring the same formula field twice will add twice the formula size to your formula. So an easy solution would be to reduce the amount of references in your formula, e.g. replace it by:

```
Commission_Percentage__c  * Subtotal__c + IF(Commission_Adjustable__c >=0,Commission_Adjustable__c,-1*Commission_Adjustable__c)
```

If I'm correct this will already get it below 5000 characters. If not, them we could also look at Commission_Percentage__c  and Subtotal__c

Comment: The formula that you have provided me is def under 5000, however its not doing what I want it to do. What I want to do is check if the Commission Adjustable is a positive number (>=0) then it has to do this: (Commission_Percentage__c  * Subtotal__c) + Commission_Adjustable__c,      but if the Comission Adjustable is a negative amount (<0) then I want it to do this:   (Commission_Percentage__c  * Subtotal__c) - Commission_Adjustable__c

Comment: I think my formula has the same result as yours. Maybe you can give an example of the inputs and an expected outcome so we can be exactly sure of your requirement?

Comment: So youre formula works for positive numbers, but not negative numbers.

Comment: In case of a negative Commission_Adjustable, it adds -1*Commission_Adjustable__c which is the same as substracting it. (Do note that substracting a negative number is equal to adding, but that is also the outcome of your version of the formula.) If we want to be really clear of your requirement, you need to add an example with numbers.

Comment: So what the problem is that its not adding nor subtracting the values correclty from the Commission Amount. For Example the Commission Amount is currently at ($1,933.97) and if I add ($4.00) to the Commission Adjustable the Commission Amount then becomes ($1,935.97). So I dont know what is exaclty goinging wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you put ,-1*Commission_Adjustable__c) and not -1+Commission_Adjustable__c) So multiply instead of add.

Comment: this is what I have in the formula field.                    (Commission_Percentage__c  * Subtotal__c) + IF(Commission_Adjustable__c >=0,Commission_Adjustable__c,-1*Commission_Adjustable__c)

Comment: Should I make Commission Adjustable a return type "Number" or leave it as "Currency"

Comment: What is the result that you want out of  above example? (Number or Currency shouldn't matter by the way)

Comment: I need it to add the $4, so the result should be $1,937.97 and if I wanted to subtract the $4, the result should be $1,929.97

Comment: If you want to substract the 4 in case the Commission_Adjustable__c is negative, then you don't even need the IF-clause. Just add Commission_Adjustable to the equation:  (Commission_Percentage__c * Subtotal__c) + Commission_Adjustable__c

Answer (score 0):

Why you do not use it as `(Commission_Percentage__c  * Subtotal__c) + Commission_Adjustable__c` ?

Comment: Because I also need to subtract a number as well. So basically Commission Percentage * Subtotal = Commission Amount. However, if you want to add or subtract from the commission amount thats where the Commission Adjustable comes in.

Comment: It will subtract because Commission_Adjustable__c will be negative. Just try my formula.

Comment: Okay so I have tried your formula and it does not correctly add or subtract values. For example, I have the Commission Amount as $660 and I made Commission Adjustable $40 so I am adding $40 to the $660 so the new Commission Amount should be $700. However, I am not getting that value, the Commission Amount comes out to $790. I have no idea how.

Comment: Try to comment Commission_Adjustable__c and see what Commission Amount is calculated - more likely `Commission_Percentage__c  * Subtotal__c' is incorrect. Try this `(Commission_Percentage__c  * Subtotal__c) /*+ Commission_Adjustable__c*/`

Comment: Well of course, that would calculate the Commission Amount I know that, but once it is calculated I want to have the power to adjust that amount. That's why I have another field called Commission Adjustable where I should be able to put in any number and it should be added to the Commission Amount.

Comment: Does it calculate it correctly? Did you get $660 as in your previous example? I just want to validate this number first

Comment: No it does not calculate it correctly.

Comment: Actually I figured out what the problem is. For example if the Commission Amount is $500, right and I try to add $50, the result will be $550. Which is correct, now if I wanted to add another $50 to the new result($550) it should be $600, but it's not, the result comes out to $550 cause it didnt save that $50 that you added previously.

Comment: Well, the formula field is operating only by the current fields values and isn't modifying any other fields. So, when you have `Commission_Percentage__c` = 10%,  `Subtotal__c` = $5,000,  `Commission_Adjustable__c` = $50, result for `(Commission_Percentage__c  * Subtotal__c) + Commission_Adjustable__c` will be $550. if you change `Commission_Adjustable__c` to $100 it will become $650...

Comment: I actually got it working, thanks for all the help that you have given!!!