# What to do when Formula Field is too big to compile

Tags: trigger, formula, error-messages, force, issue

So I am having a problem. I already have written a formula for a field that I would wish to calculate. But the problem is that the I can't add any more code to that Formula field because then it gives me a compile error saying that the formula is too big to calculate. Should I use a trigger instead? Or is there any other way I can do this? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this related to [Formula is to big to execute…What else can I use to write a formula for a field](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/128317/formula-is-to-big-to-execute-what-else-can-i-use-to-write-a-formula-for-a-fiel)?

Comment: But the problem is that I know what to code but I can't add more code to this formula field otherwise, it will say that there is a compile error. Also, I can't simplify the equation either. So I am wondering can I use the code that I have done in a trigger or workflow if possible?

Answer (score 2):

If you're already using a trigger on the object for other purposes, consider using a trigger to do the heavy lifting. Otherwise, go for either a Process Builder or Workflow Field Update.

The reason for this is that field updates will cause your triggers to run twice, potentially doubling execution time. If you have no triggers, however, using workflow rules is easier to maintain, and doesn't require lengthy deployments to change the logic later.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try to use the two that you have mentioned.